# Android FirebaseAuth undocumented `getAccessToken`

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I can't find any information on the `getAccessToken` method which can be found at `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getAccessToken(boolean)`

My Android app needs to get a JWT access token ("idToken") from Firebase in order to enable my custom backend to authenticate the user (register/sign-in).

Some playing around showed me that

```
String jwt = FirebaseAuth
                .getInstance()
                .getAccessToken(false)
                .getResult()
                .getToken();
```

as well as

```
FirebaseAuth
    .getInstance()
    .getAccessToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            String jwt = task.getResult().getToken();
        }
    });
```

appears to allow me to get such a JWT.

I've been searching for info on `getAccessToken(boolean)` but can't find anything on it. <strike>I specially want to know what the boolean value stands for; I'm guessing "async", but that feels a bit strange, as "blocking" would be a better option.</strike>

I'm concerned that since there is no documentation on this method, maybe it is deprecated or something.

Upon further checking-other-projects/googling-around I noticed that the `FirebaseUser` obtained via

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

also contains a `getIdToken(boolean)` method, which is specified as

[`public Task<GetTokenResult> getIdToken (boolean forceRefresh)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#public-taskgettokenresult-getidtoken-boolean-forcerefresh)

Is this the same one? Is the one `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` there for convenience only? Should it be avoided?

Update: They have identical behavior. If I call both with `forceRefresh=false`, they yield the same JWT.

Comment: They updated the [firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) on how to retrieve/verify tokens, still no api reference with enough detail for the `getAccessToken`

Comment: you can find it in this link https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/internal/InternalAuthProvider#public-abstract-taskgettokenresult-getaccesstoken-boolean-forcerefresh

Comment: @Faridomastr Thanks, very helpful link!